# ehcache.xml and the log4j.xml files location

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, ehcache

I maintain an old hibernate code.
I'm trying to figure out how to set ehcache.xml and log4j.xml location.(I couldn't even figure out where the log4j.xml is referred from. I guess it's somewhere in the slf4j jar [see later on], but I'm not sure )

Many answers here in stackoverflow refer to CacheManager. I think I can't use those since the persistence.xml sets hibernate.cache.region.factory_class to org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhcacheRegionFactory , not EhCacheRegionFactory .

I'm using:

ehcache 2.6.9

hibernate ehcache 4.3.5

slf4j 1.5.6 with log4j.

JDK 1.8 running in IIB 10.0.0.11 on RHEL 7.4

Comment: `ehcache.xml` and `log4j.xml` have to be in the classpath. In a webapp i.e. these file could be in `WEB-INF/classes`.

Comment: @drkunibar Running java in IIB is not like running java in web-container. Actually, those file in default have to be outside the JAR. The default location is /var/mqsi in linux.

Comment: You can set the `log4j.xml` location with the system property `-Dlog4j.configuration=/path/mylog4j.xml`. The `ehcache.xml` can used in the c'tor `CacheManager(URL)` or `CacheManager(String)`

Comment: First it depends on how you configure it, so we can't be sure of this location.
Did you use the locate or find function on unix? it could be the fastest way to find it. If you don't, it might be located here /var/mqsi/components/<YourIIBName>/<yourIntegrationServerUuid>/. To find your Integration Server uuid, you can us the ps unix command. In any cases, you have the stdout and stderr there, which contains all the Systme.out.printlf done in your java, so the logs you are looking for might be there

Comment: @Jérém I know where it is, I want to move it!

Comment: @Alaychem Due to the architecture of the Java components on IIB, I don't see the point of moving it to a different location, in my opinion it could only create concurrency issue if you mix different execution groups in the logs ... But normaly you can configure a path directly in your java source code for these logs. I've done it multiple time with other libs, but I don't know much about the lib you are using. If it can only writte on the system output, then you won't be able to change that.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the location of log4j.xml by defining an environment variable of your operation system. 
This variable is called
  `LOG4J_CONFIGURATION_FILE= <CustomLocation1> , <CustomLocation2>`

Where CustomLocation1 and CustomLocation2 are the places where the system will search for the configuration files. 
In order to set this at the start of the broker, you need to create a cmd file for windows where you have to write the batch code to set the above defined variable. 
Place this file in the following location

**\config\\profiles**

Workpath can be recognized by issuing the

> mqsireportbrokerproperties

Comment: Easier way to get workpath location is echo $MQSI_WORKPATH